# What is the maximum number of arcs that intersect at a single point (not including the center of the circle)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, recreational-mathematics, curves

Consider $n$ points evenly spaced around a circle. Connect pairs of points that are the furthest away from each other with $k$ arcs connecting each pair of points (these arcs could be pictured as evenly spaced geodesics projected straight down from the surface of a hemisphere onto the unit disk). In the interior of the disk what is maximum number of lines that intersect at one point (not including the center of the circle)? I know that the degree of intersection at the center of the circle is equal to $n/2.$

I tried drawing diagrams and thinking about this a lot but could not come to an answer. I think maybe the most lines that meet at a common point in the interior of the disk excluding the center of the circle is two or three but this is just a guess. Is there an easy way to get the correct answer?

Here's a diagram I made to visualise what's going on:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it would be clearer without a vauge and imprecise description.  Each point on the circumference is connected by an arc to the farthest k points on the circumference.   The diagram looks like crocheting.

Comment: The opposite points are connected with $k$ evenly spaced arcs? - If $k=1$, those arcs are just lines, and the only point of intersection is the center where all of the $n/2$ lines intersect, so the answer is $0$ for $(n,k)=(n,1)$? If $k$ is even, does this mean there are $0$ intersections in the center, since I assume "evenly spaced" is also symmetric relative to the center? - In all cases,  can you provide an equation that describes "$k$ evenly spaced arcs"? A start could be setting up the equation that describes the arcs and try counting the intersections.